# Querying OpenStreetMap/Nominatim Very Specifically

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geocoding, openstreetmap, nominatim

i can find a `search` parameter in nominatim when searching for addresses such as below

http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?q=CA&format=xml&addressdetails=1

I wonder if i can query something **more** **specifically**

like

`state` : `CA` or `California`

And that would return the `Country` of Origin and other information from the API

Can i do this in Nominatim without having to do a broad `search` query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other parameters(than `q`...in your query the parameter is not `search`, it's `q`),

e.g.:

- street
- city
- county
- state
- country
- postalcode

See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Special_Keywords for a complete list.

example: http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/search?state=california&format=xml&addressdetails=1

Comment: Thanks, but a search for `City=San Francisco` returns more than 5 unique locations (other cities named "San Francisco" in other countries) 

Do you have a suggestion to get accurate results given a raw address string input?

Comment: I've tried extracting cities and state from raw address string using https://github.com/datamade/usaddress  However, since this library is not 100% accurate i run a modified query into nominatum based on the partially extracted data to get an eventual lookup of the  Country name

Comment: I need to lookup the Country given the address string input